# How to pass argument to method in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to pass the fourth (targetFileCount) argument to a method as below

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("market_opt_partition.properties")
val targetFileCount = (config.getInt(Code))
writeArray1.par.foreach {
  case (df, path, tog, targetFileCount) => Utility.write(df, path, tog, targetFileCount)
}
object Utility {
    def write(sourceDf: DataFrame, path: String, toggle: String, targetFileCount:Int): Unit
```

But I am facing the below error,

```
Error:(368, 12) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2, T3, T4)
required: (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, String, String)
      case (df, path, tog, targetFileCount) => Utility.write(df, path, tog, targetFileCount)

Error:(368, 67) not found: value df
      case (df, path, tog, targetFileCount) => Utility.write(df, path, tog, targetFileCount)
```

Please let me know on how to rectify the same.

Comment: can someone explain why so many of the scala questions are getting down-votes so easily? It seems like almost every scala question is being downvoted (without a comment too)

Answer (score 1):

`writeArray1` contains tuple 3 of  `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, String, String`
So pattern matching on 4 params cannot work.

Another example:

```
val l = List(5)
l.map { case (a, b) => a.toString }
```

Also yields same error:

```
 error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Int
```

Comment: I guess the fourth argument, the int isn't part of what's actually being passed? So that's why it's not matched?

Comment: Thanks @blackwizard. Please suggest on how to pass the fourth arguement

Comment: @GamingFelix Yes that'c correct. Want to know how to resolve the same.

Comment: I think what you need to do is change the pattern matching, so it can match the 3 arguments. You can still send in the fourth argument after the matching, in the write function. I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: so like this, case (x, y, z) => Utility.write(x,y,z,fourthargument)

Answer (score 0):

As said above writeArray1.par contains tuple of 3 org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, String, String So pattern matching on 4 params cannot work.

Please use as below.

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("market_opt_partition.properties")
val targetFileCount = (config.getInt(Code))
writeArray1.par.foreach {
  case (df, path, tog) => Utility.write(df, path, tog, targetFileCount)
}
object Utility {
    def write(sourceDf: DataFrame, path: String, toggle: String, targetFileCount:Int): Unit
```